# Conditional Probability with Inequality Constraints

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose I have two initially uncorrelated random variables, $A\sim \text{Poisson}(\mu)$ and $B \sim \text{Borel}(\lambda)$.

Suppose I now apply the constraint that $P(B > A) = 0$. That is, that random variables $B$ are prohibited to be greater than $A$.

What is the probability $P(A=i \cap B=j)$?

**Attempt at a solution**

Since the total probability is limited to $A<B$, I assume that one must normalise the probability to the total probability that the event can occur.

We must therefore normalise the probability to the total allowed probability, i.e. $P(B\leq A)$

\begin{equation}
P(A>B) = P(B \leq A=i) = \sum^{i}_{k=0} P(B=k)
\end{equation}

Therefore the conditioned probability now reads:

\begin{equation}
P(A=i \cap B=j) = P(A=i)\cdot \left(\frac{P(B=j)}{\sum^{i}_{k=0} P(B=k)} \right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Your variables are not independent, clearly.

Comment: Sorry, I was told to derive this with this assumption at its core. I will amend what I have written.

Comment: This is not clear.  I thought your variables were linked, in the sense that one could not exceed the other.  If that is the case, then they are not independent.  Were you instead asking about some conditional probability?  "What is the probability that $(A,B)=(i,j)$ conditioned on the knowledge that $A≥B$"?

Comment: Precisely. This is what I am looking for. Forgive my incompetence, I am still learning.

Comment: Oh, no worries.  In that case you do just rescale by the probability that $A≥B$.

Comment: As a comment on notation:  in your formula, you use "$j$" to mean two very different things.  It is, of course, the candidate value for $B$, but you also use it as the dummy summation variable.  That's not a great idea.  Moreover, it is not clear what "$A$" refers to in that sum.  The denominator is meant to be $P(A≥B)$, which ought to be a double sum.

Comment: I have corrected it, but I am not sure why you would need a double sum in the denominator, since I am only interested in one $i$, for which there are possiblities $j\leq i$.

Comment: The denominator is $P(A≥B)$  There is no $i,j$ in that.  Thus you need $\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\sum_{b=0}^aP(a,b)$.

Comment: Work this through for a simpler distribution.  Say you are tossing a red die and a blue one.  What is the probability that both come up $4$ conditioned on the knowledge that the blue one did not exceed the red one?